# compare and mark word in strings with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

need help for this, i want to compare and mark the word like this pic

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ffdml.png

i try using js for this but got no luck

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <section class="form-group-vertical">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="1">
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="notif">
        <section class="form-group-vertical">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="2" >
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{

    var firstInput = $('#1');
    var seconInput = $('#2');

    var aa = $('#2');
    aa.change(function() {
    var n = firstInput.val().localeCompare(seconInput.val());

        if ( n === 0 ) {
            console.log('ok');
            $('#notif').attr('class', 'col-md-6');

        }
        else{
            console.log('ko');
            $('#notif').attr('class', 'has-error col-md-6');

        }
    });

});
</script>
```

any suggestion guys?

Comment: how is this a php question? there is none which makes the question unclear. why did you add it back after my edit?

Comment: sorry.. shoud i remove php tag?

Comment: if there is no relevance/code, then it's misleading to those who follow that tag and such as I do also.

Comment: js/jquery isn't my bag (I know some) but all I can say is: check your developer console and make sure you've loaded the jquery library.

Comment: i did use jquery lib, thx bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution please using this [kpdecker/jsdiff](https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff)

online demo:
[demo](http://incaseofstairs.com/jsdiff/)